# Save json as string when in a URL

Tags: java, android, json

In [this URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Portugal) I have a JSON tree that I wish to retrieve as a `String` so I can use the library I implemented `JSON` by `amirdew`. This is the code I have to parse the JSON:

```
String simpleJsonString = url;
JSON json = new JSON(simpleJsonString);
String firstTag = json.key("extract").index(0).stringValue();
txtinfo.setText(firstTag);
```

I've tried using HttpsRequest but I couldn't make it:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    try {
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error? Any way you can try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) for http request. Prase json with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: @EmptyBrain Yep. This is the error: https://pastebin.com/GdB26Nwi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an **NetworkOnMainThreadException** exception because you are trying to make an API call on the UI or Main thread. One shouldn't do any long running operations on UI thread as it is only intended for UI operations. You should either make an API call in AsyncTask or usesSome networking library like Volley or Retrofit.

[Check this out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) for the detailed description of the exception you mentioned.

**AsyncTask Implementation Of your code**

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        try {
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            is.close();
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded ");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I need to replace the Http code I have with this?

Comment: No you don't need to replace anything, I just pasted your code in AsyncTask.

Comment: I've added these 2 lines (needed) `DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();` and `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);`.
I made it and, even if there is no crash, it won't pass beside the line `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);` so it won't retrieve any json
This is my logcat https://pastebin.com/eVb3m5P7

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
Best way to used retrofit for api calling ..
add below depedency into app level gradle file..

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

after that make retrofit object like this way..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
```

}

after that define all api that you want to call..

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Portugal")
Call<Response> getData();
}
```

after that in activity call..

```
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Response> responseCall=apiInterface.getData();
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null && response!=null){
                Gson gson=new Gson();
                String data=gson.toJson(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: `Non-static method 'getInstance()' cannot be referenced from a static context` in `ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);`

Comment: make all code into separate class not single class because i am not getting any error

Comment: i update my answer change base url and api interface getData method into path.